# To lie low from someone or something

Tags: prepositions

Do we say 'He should *lie low from* the public or social media until the scandalous case has been resolved'?

Would 'stay away from' is the better option?

Comment: Yes - I would say *'stay away from' **is** the better option*. We usually use 'to lie low' as  a completely intransitive verb (you just 'lie low' to avoid attracting attention, not normally ***from*** anyone in particular who might be looking for you).

Answer (score 1):

"Stay away from" more clearly describes what is happening.

The object of "from" in the phrase "lie low from ..." is normally the thing you are hiding from:

> A village in Burgundy offers a place to lie low from the police. — [*Alain Delon*](https://ianthomasmalone.com/tag/alain-delon/)

You could combine both to say

> He should lie low and stay away from social media until the scandalous case has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

If you are involved in some kind of scandal, the media will get excited about it. The more excited they get, the more they will write/post/talk/speculate, and so more people will get to hear about it. Even if there's nothing to it, people will think "there's no smoke without fire".

The accepted way to deal with this situation is to **lie low**. According to the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lie-low), this means trying not to be noticed. Think of a rabbit lying down in the grass as a predator passes. The less you are noticed, the less the media will have to say, and eventually they will get bored with it.

**lying low** is understood to mean staying away from  **everything**- people (ie physically hide), social media (ie don't post/tweet), and everything else. It is therefore unnecessary to specify what you are lying low **from**.

It is not really necessary to say "scandalous case"... everybody will know exactly what you a referring to if you just say "scandal". This [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=scandal%2C%20scandalous%20case&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cscandal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cscandalous%20case%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cscandal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cscandalous%20case%3B%2Cc0) shows that the collocation "scandalous case" is very unusual.. about three thousand times less common than the word "scandal".

It would therefore be perfectly clear to simply say

> He should lie low until the scandal has been resolved.